# Is it possible/feasible integrate non-Microsoft REST client application in to Sharepoint 2013 OAuth to obtain an access token for a REST client?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, oauth, token

MSDN gives a javascript REST client example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022(v=office.15).aspx but they don't explain how to get the auth token.

In this question it is stated that the token cannot be obtained by client side script: [How can I get an oauth access token in sharepoint 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804624/how-can-i-get-an-oauth-access-token-in-sharepoint-2013)

The question is: is it possible and/or feasible to get this token if, say, your application is a Java enterprise app hosted on linux?

This page hints that it is possible as it states 'if you are using .NET' (implying it is possible to use other technology): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj687470.aspx

The examples and documentation all seem to assume you are using .NET, hosted on IIS or similar. E.g. this great step-by-step guide: http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-approach-to-create-a-Provider-Hosted-Application-in-SharePoint-2013

Is there documentaion/examples out there for integrating fully non-.NET applications into the Sharepoint OAuth world, i.e. a walk through like above? Or even just explicit confirmation it can be done?

One solution I've considered is creating a Sharepoint hosted app which would expose a web service to my client application and retrieve tokens on my behalf. This seems needlessly complicated and I don't want to develop and distribute a Microsoft component just for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing: authenticate on SharePoint 2013 REST APIs from android app, and it seems that the only solution is to use OAuth 2.0 for authentication:

> If you’re calling into SharePoint from a remotely hosted application
>   that can’t use client-side code (HTML and JavaScript) exclusively, and
>   there’s no firewall between SharePoint and your application, you can
>   use OAuth 2.0 tokens with Microsoft Access Control Service (ACS) as
>   the secure token server.

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I posted a possible answer (my entire Java file) on [Trying to access hosted SharePoint 2013 from Java app gives me 401 although I use correct OAuth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323613/trying-to-access-hosted-sharepoint-2013-from-java-app-gives-me-401-although-i-us/28908675#28908675).

I was trying to access a Microsoft-hosted Project Online, but couldn't figure out an easy way to solve the OAuth problem.

Hope that helps