# Trying to access hosted SharePoint 2013 from Java app gives me 401 although I use correct OAuth token

Tags: java, rest, oauth, sharepoint-2013, ntlm

I'm trying to access our company SharePoint 2013 instance, which is hosted at ourinstance.sharepoint.com, with small Java web application.

I registered application through _layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx this way:

1. I let SP generate Client ID, Client Secret,
2. to App Domain I set: ourdomain:8443
3. to Redirect URL I set: `https://ourdomain:8443/our-redirect-processing`

I edited application permissions with _layouts/15/appinv.aspx, where I looked it up by client ID and edited its Permission Request XML to contain:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://insideidc.sharepoint.com/oursite/web" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Handler behind `https://ourdomain:8443/our-redirect-processing` is doing this:

```
JsonWebSignature jws = JsonWebSignature.parse(new JacksonFactory(), request.getParameter("SPAppToken"));
JsonParser jsonParser = new JacksonFactory().createJsonParser(jws.getPayload().get("appctx").toString());
AppCtx appCtx = jsonParser.parse(AppCtx.class, new CustomizeJsonParser());
String appctxsender=jws.getPayload().get("appctxsender").toString();
String[] splitApptxSender = appctxsender.split("@");
String sharepointServerHostName = new URL(request.getParameter("SPSiteUrl")).getHost();
String resource = splitApptxSender[0] + "/" + sharepointServerHostName + "@" + splitApptxSender[1];
AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest tokenRequest = new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
    new GenericUrl(appCtx.getSecurityTokenServiceUri()), jws.getPayload().get("refreshtoken").toString());
tokenRequest.setRedirectUri(request.getRequestURL().toString());
String aud = (String) jws.getPayload().getAudience();
tokenRequest.setClientAuthentication(new ClientParametersAuthentication(aud, secrets.get(aud)));
tokenRequest.setGrantType("refresh_token");
tokenRequest.set("resource", resource);
tokenRequest.set("refresh_token", jws.getPayload().get("refreshtoken").toString());
TokenResponse response = tokenRequest.execute();
token = response.getAccessToken();
```

It uses com.google.api.client. auth, http and json classes.

The token I get I use in REST call to this URL:

```
https://ourinstance.sharepoint.com/oursite/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/thefolderIwant')/Files
```

with these Headers:

```
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Authorization: Bearer theToken
```

The response asks me for logging in, while response header has WWW-Authenticate: NTLM set.

First question: should such complex process of obtaining OAuth token end up with another credentials request?

Second and main question: how can I construct domain\username for NTLM Authenticator, which I can build, when SharePoint is hosted for us?

Comment: I ran into this same problem. One website which hinted at the answer was [AllThatJS](http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/).   After using Fiddler to sniff my HTTPS packets, I finally came up with Java solution, using the Apache HttpClient.jar, and Apache common-io.jar. I can post my Java code here, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience when trying to access Microsoft's Project Online.
I found some helpful information from [AllThatJS](http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/) which pointed me in the right direction. He suggested sniffing the packets using Fiddler. Once I did that, I saw what was actually going on.
Here is some Java code I used to solve this problem, using Apache's HttpClient, Apache's common-io, and log4j to solve this :

```
/**

    This is for using Java to connect with Microsoft's Project Online

    If you go into your Project Online, go to 'Server Settings' -> 'Manage Users', and look under the column 'User Logon Account'

    If it looks like :
        i:0#.w|domain\\username
    then you can just scroll down to where I call 

                httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                        new AuthScope(url.getHost(), url.getPort(), AuthScope.ANY_REALM, AuthScope.ANY_SCHEME),
                        new NTCredentials(
                                USERNAME,
                                PASSWORD,
                                url.getHost(), 
                                DOMAIN));


    However, if it looks more like :
        i:0#.f|membership|username@yourcompany.com
    then you'll need to use OAuth, which is what this file demonstrates.

*/

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.UUID;


import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;// from commons-io-2.4.jar
import org.apache.http.Header;// from httpcore-4.2.4.jar
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;// from log4j.jar
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ProjectOnline {

    private static final Logger logger         = Logger.getLogger(ProjectOnline.class);

    private static final String USERNAME       = "your user's email address";
    private static final String PASSWORD       = "password";
    private static final String DOMAIN         = "YOURDOMAIN";
    private static final String PROJECT_SERVER = "https://your.project.online.sharepoint.com";
    private static final String EMAIL_DOMAIN   = "@your.company.com";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProjectOnline dao = new ProjectOnline();
        System.out.println(dao.getOAuthCookie());

    }

    private boolean needToUseOAuth(String username) {
        if (username == null) return false;
        return username.toLowerCase().endsWith(EMAIL_DOMAIN.toLowerCase());
    }

    public String getOAuthCookie() {

        if (needToUseOAuth(USERNAME)) {

            String samlSecurityToken = postLoginCredentialsToOurOAuthService();

            if (samlSecurityToken != null && samlSecurityToken.isEmpty() == false) {

                String binarySecurityToken = postSamlSecurityTokenToSecondSite(samlSecurityToken);

                if (binarySecurityToken != null && binarySecurityToken.isEmpty() == false) {

                    String spoidcrlCookie = getSpoidcrlCookie(binarySecurityToken);
                    return spoidcrlCookie;
                } else {
                    //System.out.println("getXMLDocument - OAuth authentication / authorization failed : Binary Security Token was not found");
                    logger.error("getOAuthCookie - OAuth authentication / authorization failed : Binary Security Token was not found");
                }
            } else {
                //System.out.println("getXMLDocument - OAuth authentication / authorization failed : SAML Security Token was not found");
                logger.error("getOAuthCookie - OAuth authentication / authorization failed : SAML Security Token was not found");
            }
        }

        return "";
    }

    // Step 1 - Find the URL to your company's OAuth site
    private String getOurOAuthServerURL(String emailAddress) {

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Go to this site, passing in email address. Should tell the URL for your company's OAuth site
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://login.microsoftonline.com/GetUserRealm.srf?xml=1&login=" + emailAddress);

        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String status = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            //System.out.println("getOurOAuthServerURL - status = " + status);
            logger.info("getOurOAuthServerURL - status = " + status);

            // If response status doesn't equal 'OK' then it didn't work.
            if (entity != null && "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".equals(status)) {

                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(entity.getContent(), writer, "utf-8");
                String xml = writer.toString();

                //System.out.println(xml);
                //logger.debug(xml);

                String ourAuthURL = getSTSAuthURL(xml);
                //System.out.println("ourAuthURL = " + ourAuthURL);
                return ourAuthURL;

            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            logger.error("getOurOAuthServerURL ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            logger.error("getOurOAuthServerURL ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            logger.error("getOurOAuthServerURL ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("getOurOAuthServerURL ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
        return "";
    }

    private String getBinarySecurityToken(String xml) {
        return getValuesBetweenTags(xml, "<wsse:BinarySecurityToken Id=\"Compact0\">", "</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>");
    }

    private String getSTSAuthURL(String xml) {
        return getValuesBetweenTags(xml, "<STSAuthURL>", "</STSAuthURL>");
    }

    private String getSamlSecurityToken(String xml) {
        return getValuesBetweenTags(xml, "<t:RequestedSecurityToken>", "</t:RequestedSecurityToken>");
    }

    private String getValuesBetweenTags(String xml, String tagToLeft, String tagToRight) {
        if (xml == null || xml.isEmpty()) return "";

        int startToken = xml.indexOf(tagToLeft);
        if (startToken > -1) {
            return xml.substring(startToken + tagToLeft.length(), xml.indexOf(tagToRight, startToken));
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private String getTimeString(int minutesInFuture) {
        Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        rightNow.add(Calendar.SECOND, (((rightNow.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + (rightNow.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)))/-1000)));
        rightNow.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesInFuture);
        String timeString = String.format("%d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d.0000000Z", 
                                     rightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                                    (rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1), 
                                     rightNow.get(Calendar.DATE), 
                                     rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                                     rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                                     rightNow.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        return timeString;
    }

    // Step 2 - POST an XML message, with a few key fields filled in (rest can be left as-is)
    // This should be sent to your company's OAuth site
    private String postLoginCredentialsToOurOAuthService() {

        String ourOAuthService = getOurOAuthServerURL(USERNAME);

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder();

        xmlString.append("<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" ");
        xmlString.append("xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\"  ");
        xmlString.append("xmlns:saml=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion\"  ");
        xmlString.append("xmlns:wsp=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy\"  ");
        xmlString.append("xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\"  ");
        xmlString.append("xmlns:wsa=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\"  ");
        xmlString.append("xmlns:wssc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc\"  ");
        xmlString.append("xmlns:wst=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust\"> ");
        xmlString.append("<s:Header> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsa:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</wsa:Action> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsa:To s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">" + ourOAuthService + "</wsa:To> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsa:MessageID>").append(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).append("</wsa:MessageID> ");
        xmlString.append("<ps:AuthInfo xmlns:ps=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/PPCRL\" Id=\"PPAuthInfo\"> ");
        xmlString.append("<ps:HostingApp>Managed IDCRL</ps:HostingApp> ");
        xmlString.append("<ps:BinaryVersion>6</ps:BinaryVersion> ");
        xmlString.append("<ps:UIVersion>1</ps:UIVersion> ");
        xmlString.append("<ps:Cookies></ps:Cookies> ");
        xmlString.append("<ps:RequestParams>AQAAAAIAAABsYwQAAAAxMDMz</ps:RequestParams> ");
        xmlString.append("</ps:AuthInfo> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsse:Security> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=\"user\"> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsse:Username>").append(USERNAME).append("</wsse:Username> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsse:Password>").append(PASSWORD).append("</wsse:Password> ");
        xmlString.append("</wsse:UsernameToken> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsu:Timestamp Id=\"Timestamp\"> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsu:Created>" + getTimeString(0) + "</wsu:Created> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsu:Expires>" + getTimeString(10) + "</wsu:Expires> ");
        xmlString.append("</wsu:Timestamp> ");
        xmlString.append("</wsse:Security> ");
        xmlString.append("</s:Header> ");
        xmlString.append("<s:Body> ");
        xmlString.append("<wst:RequestSecurityToken Id=\"RST0\"> ");
        xmlString.append("<wst:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</wst:RequestType> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsp:AppliesTo> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsa:EndpointReference> ");
        xmlString.append("<wsa:Address>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</wsa:Address> ");
        xmlString.append("</wsa:EndpointReference> ");
        xmlString.append("</wsp:AppliesTo> ");
        xmlString.append("<wst:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</wst:KeyType> ");
        xmlString.append("</wst:RequestSecurityToken> ");
        xmlString.append("</s:Body> ");
        xmlString.append("</s:Envelope> ");

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(ourOAuthService);

        try {

            httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");

            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(xmlString.toString()));// Set this in the body

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String status = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            //System.out.println("postLoginCredentialsToOurOAuthService - status = " + status);
            logger.info("postLoginCredentialsToOurOAuthService - status = " + status);

            // If response status doesn't equal 'OK' then it didn't work.
            if (entity != null && "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".equals(status)) {

                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(entity.getContent(), writer, "utf-8");
                String xml = writer.toString();

                //System.out.println(xml);
                //logger.debug(xml);

                // Now, extract out the SAML Security Token. It is several lines (~49, if you parse it out).
                String samlSecurityToken = getSamlSecurityToken(xml);
                //System.out.println("samlSecurityToken = " + samlSecurityToken);
                return samlSecurityToken;

            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            logger.error("postLoginCredentialsToOurOAuthService ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            logger.error("postLoginCredentialsToOurOAuthService ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            logger.error("postLoginCredentialsToOurOAuthService ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("postLoginCredentialsToOurOAuthService ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Step 3 - Now that you have the SAML Security Token, you embed it within some other generic XML, and send back to Microsoft server
    private String postSamlSecurityTokenToSecondSite(String samlSecurityToken) {

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://login.microsoftonline.com/rst2.srf");

            httppost.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)");

            StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder();

            xmlString.append("<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" ");
            xmlString.append("xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" ");
            xmlString.append("xmlns:wsp=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy\" ");
            xmlString.append("xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\" ");
            xmlString.append("xmlns:wsa=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" ");
            xmlString.append("xmlns:wst=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust\">");
            xmlString.append("<S:Header>");
            xmlString.append("<wsa:Action S:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</wsa:Action>");
            xmlString.append("<wsa:To S:mustUnderstand=\"1\">https://login.microsoftonline.com/rst2.srf</wsa:To>");
            xmlString.append("<ps:AuthInfo xmlns:ps=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveID/SoapServices/v1\" Id=\"PPAuthInfo\">");
            xmlString.append("<ps:BinaryVersion>5</ps:BinaryVersion>");
            xmlString.append("<ps:HostingApp>Managed IDCRL</ps:HostingApp>");
            xmlString.append("</ps:AuthInfo>");
            xmlString.append("<wsse:Security>");
            xmlString.append(samlSecurityToken);
            xmlString.append("</wsse:Security>");
            xmlString.append("</S:Header>");
            xmlString.append("<S:Body>");
            xmlString.append("<wst:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:wst=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust\" Id=\"RST0\">");
            xmlString.append("<wst:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</wst:RequestType>");
            xmlString.append("<wsp:AppliesTo>");
            xmlString.append("<wsa:EndpointReference>");
            xmlString.append("<wsa:Address>sharepoint.com</wsa:Address>");
            xmlString.append("</wsa:EndpointReference>");
            xmlString.append("</wsp:AppliesTo>");
            xmlString.append("<wsp:PolicyReference URI=\"MBI\"></wsp:PolicyReference>");
            xmlString.append("</wst:RequestSecurityToken>");
            xmlString.append("</S:Body>");
            xmlString.append("</S:Envelope>");

            httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");

            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(xmlString.toString()));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String status = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            //System.out.println("postSamlSecurityTokenToSecondSite - status = " + status);
            logger.info("postSamlSecurityTokenToSecondSite - status = " + status);

            // If response status doesn't equal 'OK' then it didn't work.
            if (entity != null && "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".equals(status)) {

                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(entity.getContent(), writer, "utf-8");
                String xml = writer.toString();

                //System.out.println(xml);
                //logger.debug(xml);

                // Extract out the value from just one, single line of this returned XML file
                String binarySecurityToken = getBinarySecurityToken(xml);
                //System.out.println("binarySecurityToken = " + binarySecurityToken);
                return binarySecurityToken;

            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            logger.error("postSamlSecurityTokenToSecondSite ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            logger.error("postSamlSecurityTokenToSecondSite ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            logger.error("postSamlSecurityTokenToSecondSite ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("postSamlSecurityTokenToSecondSite ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

        return "";
    }

    // Step 4 - Using the extracted value, the Binary Security Token, build a header, and add it to the next request
    // This will go to your own Project Online server, which should return back a reply message, containing a 'Set-Cookie' cookie with 'SPOIDCRL' in the value
    private String getSpoidcrlCookie(String binarySecurityToken) {
        try {

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(PROJECT_SERVER + "/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/");

            httpget.addHeader("Authorization", "BPOSIDCRL " + binarySecurityToken);

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            String status = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            //System.out.println("getSpoidcrlCookie - status = " + status);
            logger.info("getSpoidcrlCookie - status = " + status);

            // If response status doesn't equal 'OK' then it didn't work.
            if ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK".equals(status)) {

                Header[] headers = response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie");
                for (Header header : headers) {
                    if (header.getValue().contains("SPOIDCRL")) {
                        String spoidcrlCookie = header.getValue();
                        //System.out.println("Found SPOIDCRL cookie : " + spoidcrlCookie);
                        return spoidcrlCookie;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            logger.error("getSpoidcrlCookie ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("getSpoidcrlCookie ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("getSpoidcrlCookie ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Document getXMLDocument(String strURL) {

        String spoidcrlCookie = getOAuthCookie();

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(strURL);

        try {

            URL url = new URL(strURL);

            if (needToUseOAuth(USERNAME)) {

                httpget.addHeader("Cookie", spoidcrlCookie);

            } else {

                // Otherwise, can just use this simple way of logging in, using the Domain
                httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                        new AuthScope(url.getHost(), url.getPort(), AuthScope.ANY_REALM, AuthScope.ANY_SCHEME),
                        new NTCredentials(
                                USERNAME,
                                PASSWORD,
                                url.getHost(), 
                                DOMAIN));

            }

            //System.out.println("getXMLDocument - strURL " + strURL);
            //logger.info("getXMLDocument - strURL " + strURL);
            //logger.info("getXMLDocument - executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);//httppost
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            //logger.info("getXMLDocument - ----------------------------------------");
            //for (Header header : response.getAllHeaders()) {
            //  System.out.println("getXMLDocument - header = " + header.toString());
            //}
            String status = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            //System.out.println("getXMLDocument - status = " + status);
            //logger.info("getXMLDocument - status = " + status);

            // If response status doesn't equal 'OK' then it didn't work.
            if (entity != null && "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".equals(status)) {

                DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(entity.getContent(), writer, "utf-8");
                String xml = writer.toString();

                //System.out.println(xml);
                //logger.debug(xml);

                if (xml.endsWith("</feed>") == false) {
                    //logger.warn("The XML did not end with </feed>");
                    xml = xml + "</feed>";
                }

                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                Document doc = docBuilder.parse(inputStream);
                return doc;

            } else {

                logger.error("getXMLDocument - status = " + status);

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            logger.error("getXMLDocument ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("getXMLDocument ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            logger.error("getXMLDocument ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            logger.error("getXMLDocument ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            logger.error("getXMLDocument ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("getXMLDocument ERROR | SHORT ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage() + " FULL ERROR MESSAGE: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

        logger.warn("Exiting from getXMLDocument but returning null");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your suggestion is what I actually did at the end = use one user for logging into SharePoint and performing all actions as that single user. However, with OAuth one should be able to perform actions as another user without having to know his password. This I did not manage to do.

Comment: Any luck with this using Oauth? Has Authorization type Bearer worked for anyone?