# Javascript with SharePoint 2013 REST Endpoint "INSERT" into List?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2013, crud, sharepoint-list

Here are what i'm going to use:

- SharePoint 2013
- Javascript
- REST Endpoint
- SharePoint List *(called: "Announcements")*
- WebSite *(called: "example.com")*

Refs:

- http://www.plusconsulting.com/blog/2013/05/crud-on-list-items-using-rest-services-jquery/
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn292552.aspx

Very simply:

- How do i INSERT a new item (row) inside the List please?

I tried:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Announcements')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify( { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.AnnouncementListItem' }, "Title": "New Announcement!" } ),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
        "X-RequestDigest": form digest value,
        "IF-MATCH": etag,
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

---

Then i know a lot of things go wrong especially in `headers` section. But what does it mean by:

- `Authorization`
- `accessToken`
- `X-RequestDigest`
- `IF-MATCH`

.. and then HOW TO get these values (with JavaScript)? So that:

- What are always the exact required fields there?
- And how/where to get these values from?

I still can not find a simple and complete example about doing this `Update` / `Insert` properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get an oauth access token in sharepoint 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804624/how-can-i-get-an-oauth-access-token-in-sharepoint-2013)

Answer (score 1):

So there are two ways that I have used to submit an item to a list, the jQuery library SPServices and REST API's. SPServices is really well documented [here](https://spservices.codeplex.com/). Using REST API's is much faster and pretty easy too!

```js
function createListItem(itemProperties, success, failure) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Announcements",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      success(data.d);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      // failure(data.responseJSON.error);
      alert("error");
    }
  });
}
```

First thing I am doing above is creating a function that you can call whenever you want to create a new list item. The parameter itemProperties can be populated with the fields which you need, see below.

```js
var Title = "Title";
var Answer = "Answer";
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

var taskProperties = {
  'Title': Title,
  'Answer': Answer,
  'UserId': userid
};
```

Then all we have to do is call this function with the new variable we just declared.

```js
createListItem(taskProperties, function(task) {
    alert("Thank you for your input!");

  },
  function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi moon, thank you so much for this. Do i still need to put ` "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() ` into the `headers: ` section? Bcos it is still not getting saved. And can `url: ` be like `"https://example.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Announcements')/items"`?

Comment: But also not showing error. Succeeded instead. But not really saved.

Comment: @夏期劇場 I did not use "X-RequestDigest" so try doing it without first to see if it works. If you are using a SharePoint hosted app then you can try doing `"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()`. As for the url, I think you can remove the /items from the url that you used and that should work. `"https://example.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Announcements')"`

Comment: Hi @moon thanks again. But i'm still not getting the items saved. Is the `Authorization: ` header also required? I've tried calling the `.js` file from the masterpage way. And another way by putting the whole codes inside the SP WebPart (ScriptEditor) so that i assume the Authorization shouldn't be required. Am i correct please?

Comment: @夏期劇場 can you please post what your current code looks like in a jsFiddle and share the link here?

Comment: Hi moon, nevermind about the approach above. I've now found out another approach and it is working. Here is my codes in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzyts8f4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Actually jsfiddle which you have posted in the previous commend is not the REST . you just use the SharePoint client object model. find below the REST API model I hope it will work

```
var cat = {
    "__metadata": { "type": ItemType },
    "Title": "GenIT-Issue",
}
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tickets')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(cat),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
```

I run this code inside my SharePoint page so there is no authentication required. it will run on current user privilege