# How can I retrieve a Sharepoint 2013 document using RPGLE?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I need to programmatically retrieve a document from Sharepoint 2013 for use in an RPGLE program running on an IBM i. Has anyone ever done anything similar? At the very least, if I can get the document out of Sharepoint and onto a network file share I know how to grab it from there. I've explored many different possibilities but I don't know C# or .NET and I'm struggling to find something that I can adapt to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: 
I was able to achieve what I was trying to do by using Scott Klement's open source HTTPAPI in an RPG program:

```
   Ctl-opt DftActGrp(*No);
   Ctl-opt BndDir('HTTPAPI');

  /include libhttp/qrpglesrc,httpapi_h

   Dcl-s rc       Int(10);
   Dcl-s url      Varchar(300);
   Dcl-s ifs      Varchar(256);
   Dcl-s pwtype   Char(1);
   Dcl-s userid   Char(50);
   Dcl-s password Char(50);

  // Turn on debugging for troubleshooting. It will write a debug log file
  // to the IFS in /tmp/httpapi_debug.txt
   http_debug(*ON);

   url = 'http://sharepoint/path/to/file/thefile.pdf';
   ifs = '/temp/myfile.pdf';

  // Set password type for SharePoint's NTLM authentication requirement
   pwtype = HTTP_AUTH_NTLM;

  // Set user and password
   userid = 'theuser';
   password = 'thepassword';

  // Set credentials for authentication
   http_setAuth(pwtype: userid: password);

  // Call HTTPAPI's routine to download the file to the IFS
   rc = http_req('GET': url: ifs);

  // End gracefully if error
   if rc <> 1;
     http_crash();
   endif;

   *inlr = *on;
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.code400.com/forum/forum/iseries-programming-languages/rpg-rpgle/144502-retrieve-a-sharepoint-2013-document-from-an-rpg-program).

Answer (score 1):

You can access SharePoint 2013 data over REST API, if RPGLE supports it. 
You might need to set up proper authentication for the same.

The documentation for the REST API can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can parse your document in RPG, you can use the sql function HTTPGETBLOB with the sharepoint REST API GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl to [retrieve a document via HTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn292553.aspx)

Use the HTTPGETBLOB SQL function in a SQLRPGLE. Example here [IBM i SQL HTTP Services](http://www.mcpressonline.com/programming/web-languages/techtip-db2-for-i-http-functions-part-2-request-and-response-header-fields) , be sure to pass sharepoint authorisation/token in header:

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/file name')/$value
method: GET
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
```

If your document is long, you should write it in IFS, as explained it the previous link, otherwise the RPG variable length may be not sufficient.

Comment: This sounds like a great solution, Dam. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it works out. Thanks!

Comment: Dam, any idea how to get the accessToken for the Authorization header in the SQLRPGLE?

Comment: I've successfully used this method with Alfresco and not Sharepoint. The auth token is very easy to obtain with Alfresco. I don't currently use sharepoint and I assumed it was straightforward, but it seems tricky to obtain the token, I searched a little but couldn't find a definitive answer, see [how-can-i-get-an-oauth-access-token-in-sharepoint-2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804624/how-can-i-get-an-oauth-access-token-in-sharepoint-2013).

Comment: It seems difficult even in javascript, so in RPG... Faced to such a difficult process, personally I would find a Java library to do this for me : the login/retrieval of the file in the IFS, and call it from RPG. I saw "Jshare API" or [sharepoint-rest-interface](https://github.com/clintonbosch/sharepoint-rest-interface)

Comment: Thanks, Dam. I did a lot of searching before posing that 2nd question to you and ran into the same stumbling blocks. Back to the drawing board I guess. Your overall technique for grabbing the document, however, is really helfpul. Definitely one to keep in my toolbox.