# How can I read a SharePoint list from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, azure, sharepoint

I need to read and create a SharePoint list from a JavaScript file on my localhost. How can I do this? I think I need to get credentials via oAuth but I'm not really sure

I know there is a library called http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices but I'm not sure if I can read outside sharepoint portal.

Answer (score 0):

I never used this library [`sympmarc/SPServices`](https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices), but it seems not to restrict for use outside sharepoint portal after I researched it slightly.

Meanwhile, I think you can refer to the offical document [`Working with lists and list items with REST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest) to directly use the SharePoint REST service to read a list.

And for how to get credentials via OAuth, there is a similar SO thread [How can I get an oauth access token in sharepoint 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804624/how-can-i-get-an-oauth-access-token-in-sharepoint-2013) which you can refer to. Then, you will know the correct way is to obtain an access token for REST API calling, which be introduced in the section [`Reading data with the SharePoint REST interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#reading-data-with-the-sharepoint-rest-interface) of the document `Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints`, as below.

> For more information about how you can obtain an access token, see [Context Token OAuth flow for SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/context-token-oauth-flow-for-sharepoint-add-ins) and [Authorization Code OAuth flow for SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/authorization-code-oauth-flow-for-sharepoint-add-ins).
>   `